# Monitor not detected

Tags: kubuntu, xorg, multiple-monitors, display, xrandr

Seems like there's a few of these questions, but none of the solutions in the previous questions have helped me.

I have 2 monitors. Both plugged into my GPU (GTX750ti); one via HDMI and one via VGA. I moved the VGA one to the Motherboard as part of setting up GPU passthrough to a VM. I have now moved it back to my GPU, however the monitor no longer sees any input from the card, and is not detected by `xrandr` at all.

The monitor still functions perfectly. It works fine during splash and showing the BIOS, it just stops receiving input once the display manager loads.

I am at a complete loss how to resolve this. I've heard of clearing monitor settings through `rm ~/.config/monitors.xml` but as far as I can tell I have no such file. How do I either reset things so that Kubuntu auto-detects it again, or else manually tell it the monitor is there?

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, still no idea why it wasn't working in the VGA port of the graphics card but I did the following, and it now works in the motherboard VGA port which is what I wanted anyway:

1. Added intel_agp and i915 to /etc/initramfs-tools/modules
2. Added i915.modeset=1 to the grub options
3. Ran `sudo update-grub && sudo update-initramfs -u`

and that seems to have done the trick